# Intellij's live inspection fails to find external references in ANT build files

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I have a project with different modules bundled into each others.
We build with ant and I have no problem running the Ant build inside Intellij if I provide the path to the generic build files through a property (repository.dir : C:/myRepositoryFolder).

Similarly, I have no problem running my ant build in command line given I have set my environment variable ANT-OPTS with -Drepository.dir=C:/myRepositoryFolder

However, Intellij does not know where to find this folder and therefore the inspection 'Ant inspections / **Ant references resolve problems**' blow off on most of my build.xml.

Does anybody know where I can show Intellij where to find this folder *without modifying my existent build.properties*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question might be linked but has not be answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994664/is-there-a-way-to-pass-inherited-intellij-project-structure-properties-to-inte